# arcpy FromWKT to functioning in_memory layer to be used in geoprocessing tools

Tags: arcpy, geometry, well-known-text

As part of a larger script I am extracting postgis geometries from WKT(got that part down) then I am trying to create an in_memory polygon geometry to be used in arcpy tools.

so far:

```
    postgis_layer="select ST_Astext(st_force2d(shape)) from {}".format(fc2)
    print postgis_layer
    cur.execute(postgis_layer)
    #good until here!
    in_mry=arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.FromWKT((x for x in cur)))
    print in_mry
    #arcpy.Union_analysis(fc1,in_mry,output)
```

how do I go from arcpy.FromWKT to the arcpy.Polygon? then can I use that in the union tool? I do not want to save the geometries from postgis as feature classes

```
    postgis_layer="select ST_Astext(st_force2d(shape)) from {}".format(fc2)
    print postgis_layer
    cur.execute(postgis_layer)
    geoms=arcpy.Array()
    for geom in cur:
        print geom[0]
        geoms.add(arcpy.FromWKT(geom[0]))
    in_mry=arcpy.Polygon(geoms)
    print in_mry
    #arcpy.Union_analysis(fc1,in_mry,output)



select ST_Astext(st_force2d(shape)) from rmp_indicators.total_forest
POLYGON((535836.248384263 740131.124948196,535934.437164262 740343.250836283,535909.998236761 740114.438629866,535836.248384263 740131.124948196))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R:\Data\LUCZ_2017\Python_Scripts\Unclassified_Areas.py", line 53, in <module>
    p.union_fcs('blah','rmp_indicators.total_forest','b')
  File "R:\Data\LUCZ_2017\Python_Scripts\Unclassified_Areas.py", line 43, in union_fcs
    geoms.add(arcpy.FromWKT(geom[0]))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line 48, in add
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.Add(*gp_fixargs(args)))
ValueError: Array: Add input not point nor array object
```

so I got until here:

```
    polys=[arcpy.FromWKT(geom[0]) for geom in cur]
    for x in polys:
        print x
    poly=arcpy.Polygon(polys)
```

polys works, but I do not know how to pass polys into the arcpy.Polygon

x prints out

```
<geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x24FAC2E0>
<geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x24FAC320>
<geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x24FAC360>
<geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x24FAC3A0>
<geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x24FAC3E0>
<geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x24FAC420>
<geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x24FAC460>
<geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x24FAC4A0>
<geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x24FAC4E0>
<geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x24FAC520>
```

so clearly the geometries are there, I just do not know how to pass them into the Polygon geometry. I am going to just try and use polys as the input to the union tool, maybe the arcpy.FromWKT automatically turns it into a functioning Polygon because it is one

Comment: This is an extremely convoluted route for what would be a very simple Query Layer utilization exercise. This may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), better solved by asking for a solution to the root problem than to the problematic methodology.

Comment: good point Vince, I have not thought of that option and that might work well. However I must add I have had very shaky experience with postgres to arc and back and forth. I understand its read and write with 10.4.1 or greater but I have found if I make edits in postgresql, Arc does not like those changes

Comment: ArcGIS expects valid topology, which is not entirely unreasonable.

Comment: @Vince for sure, I would say the lack of valid topology is something that is lacking on the PostGIS end. Then again, they use different geometry models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring this out:

Essenitally the `arcpy.FromWKT()` will create the actual geometries you pass through it. I was under the assumption based on other ESRI geometry constructors that this would have to be passed at least through the `arcpy.Polygon` constructor if not the `arcpy.Array()`. The documentation is pretty sparse for this `arcpy.FromWKT()` but whatever you pass through will be ready to use geometries

```
postgis_layer="select ST_Astext(st_force2d(shape)) from {}".format(fc2)
cur.execute(postgis_layer)
polys=[arcpy.FromWKT(geom[0]) for geom in cur]
mem = r"in_memory\polygons"
memory_layer=arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polys,mem)
arcpy.Union_analysis([fc1,memory_layer],output)
```